# How to trim, crop, and concatenate a reverse into video at the same time

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to first trim and crop the video, then take the output and concatenate a reverse of that onto the video. The way I'm doing it now requires me to run two commands. Is there a way to simplify it into a single command?

Currently, I'm running
        `ffmpeg -i MVI_0289.mov -ss 00:00:10.50 -t 3 -vf "crop=720:720:600:80" -movflags +faststart -an OUTPUT.mp4`

and then
        `ffmpeg -i OUTPUT.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]reverse,fifo[r];[0:v][r] concat=n=2:v=1 [v]" -map "[v]" OUTPUT2.mp4`

Update#1: Running `ffmpeg -ss 00:00:10.50 -t 3 -i MVI_0289.mov
-filter_complex "reverse,fifo[r];[0:v][r] concat=n=2:v=1,crop=720:720:600:80[v]" -map "[v]" OUTPUT2.mp4`
 gives the following error:
`ffmpeg -ss 00:00:10.50 -t 3 -i MVI_0289.mov
ffmpeg version 3.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.4 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-ffplay --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'MVI_0289.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt

    minor_version   : 537331968
    compatible_brands: qt  CAEP
    com.apple.quicktime.make: Canon
    com.apple.quicktime.model: Canon EOS 70D
    com.apple.quicktime.rating.user: 0.000000
    creation_time   : 2017-12-09T23:42:21.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:19.19, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 25320 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25277 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 48k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-12-09T23:42:21.000000Z
      timecode        : 00:16:56:04
    Stream #0:1(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-12-09T23:42:21.000000Z
      timecode        : 00:16:56:04
At least one output file must be specified
-filter_complex "reverse,fifo[r];[0:v][r] concat=n=2:v=1,crop=720:720:600:80[v]" -map "[v]" OUTPUT2.mp4
-bash: -filter_complex: command not found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:10.50 -t 3 -i MVI_0289.mov -filter_complex "reverse,fifo[r];[0:v][r] concat=n=2:v=1,crop=720:720:600:80[v]" -map "[v]" OUTPUT2.mp4
```

Comment: I get an error `At least one output file must be specified` and then `-bash: -vf: command not found`.

Comment: @smartbean Change `-vf` to `-filter_complex`. If that doesn't work show your full command and the complete console output.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard That did not work either. Please see update to the question.

Comment: @smartbean You were actually splitting the command in half and trying to run each half independently. The linebreak was for readability and should be removed before executing the command. Try the updated command.

Comment: Oops, forgot to change the `-vf` in the original.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard It worked after running `ffmpeg -ss 00:00:10.50 -t 3 -i MVI_0289.mov -filter_complex "reverse,fifo[r];[0:v][r]concat=n=2:v=1,crop=720:720:600:80[v]" -map "[v]" OUTPUT2.mp4
` Thanks a lot to you both!